# What JavaScript features / version can be used in a Apache Cordova plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-ios, cordova-android, cordova-windows

I am writing a plugin for Apache Cordova (targeting the Cordova iOS, Android and Windows platforms) and wondered what JavaScript features or ECMAScript version I can use in my `.js` files of the plugin.

Cordova Android seems to [support Android 4.4 - 9](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support), Cordova iOS [everything from iOS 9](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#requirements-and-support). Cordova Windows [doesn't have any compatibility information](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/windows/index.html). Even that of course doesn't really tell me too much about what kind of JavaScript support I can expect from the webview - especially on Android where this can be independent from the OS.

What JavaScript features / version can be used in a Apache Cordova plugin?

Comment: it depends almost entirely on the android version. refer to charts for specifics. 4.4 is missing a lot of modern stuff like template strings and fat arrow functions.

Comment: If you want to be compatible, ES5 only

Comment: As @Eric says - assume ES5. If you want to use newer ES features, include an ES5 polyfill e.g https://github.com/es-shims/es6-shim